# "Failed to load module script / MIME" error when trying to use JS with a pdf.js library on a live-server through VScode

Tags: javascript, server, module, libraries

I'm currently working on a project that will automatically fill a specific PDF document with user input information in an HTML form.

Before even getting to the actual JS coding, I've been having issues with getting the PDF.js library imported properly. The initial error I got basically told me that I cannot import the PDF.js library when running the index.html on my own machine, so I need to use a live server. **Que VSCode live-server extension.**

Now that I have the Live-server extension running, this is the new error in the console:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. --- :5500/node_modules/pdf.js/:1
```

I've been using a combination of ChatGPT and Google in order to find the issue. The picture attached shows what ChatGPT is recommending [ChatGPT recommendation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfgDM.jpg)

Based one that, it seems that by default, the VSCode live-server extension doesn't work well with modules and JS? (or am I misunderstanding that?)

It basically sent me to the `.ritwickdey.liveserver` directory within `./vscode/extensions` looking for a `mime.types` **file.** However, the closest thing I've found is a `mime.types` **folder,** containing the following: `History.md`, `index.js`, `LICENSE`, `package.json`, and `README.md`. I understand that things might not be exactly as the AI (or google) says, but for the life of me, I cannot find the file that needs to be changed in order to allow the module to work. Does anyone have any idea?

I linked my `main.js` file in the `HTML.index`, and imported the pdfjs library within the `main.js` file. Is that correct?

```
 <script src="./main.js" type="module"></script>
```

```
 import * as pdfjs from './node_modules/pdf.js';
```

Also... am I just going about this in an extremely round about way? Like is there a simple solution to this that I'm just completely overlooking? I feel like it shouldn't be this complicated. I'm still fairly new to this though so I guess it could be.

P.S - This is my first post on Stack Overflow, so hopefully it is well written :) Please let me know if I need to add any more information

1. I have tried looking for the `mime.types` file mentioned above, but have had no luck locating it.
2. I've played around with the  and importing

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I suggest you to remove anything that you have taken from ChatGPT as there are several reports that it's not reliable (the same prompt might get good/bad recommendations). Ref. [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). Please add a [mcve].